# Amazon SimpleDB Web Page Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I am a new developer to the AWS cloud. I am writing an Android App that interfaces with the SimpleDB. I have found many references and have successfully interfaced my app with the SimpleDB using the AWS SDK and using the anonymous TVM - works great.

The problem is I will need a web site to interface to the same data via AWS SimpleDB. The web site also needs to interface with Google Maps. For the first phase, the site can be completely private, but down the road I would want to be able to make the site available to the public, utilizing one set of security Credentials.

After reading some of the documentation - I am extremely confused about how to do this. Do I need to host the site on AWS? Which API do I use that could interface with my web site code-mostly JQUERY and JavaScript? I see there is a PHP API? (Not too familiar with PHP) I saw some examples using REST calls via AJAX. If anyone has any feedback or simple examples, or explanations that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should host your web site on an EC2 instance (although you can host it on any other server or hosting service).

Your site should also integrate with AWS services, like SimpleDB or DynamoDB.

It will be easier for you to start with Node.js that will run your JQuery and other JavaScript code natively. Check out the new [SDK for Node.js](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/nodejs/latest/dg/nodejs-dg-aws-sdk-for-node.js.html).

Comment: It doesnt appear that SDK for Node.js interfaces with SimplDB - only DynamoDB

Comment: DynamoDB and SimpleDB have rather similar interface, and DynamoDB is much better in scale. Having this SDK support is another good reason to use DynamoDB in your app.

Comment: Thanks Guy - I think I'll move in that direction - DynamoDb.  I looked at the link for the Node.js SDK and it looks pretty straightforward.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a static site of mostly js and HTML, you can use amazon s3 to host your site.